# Install Software with MSIEXEC with GPO Shutdown Script

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, group-policy, scripting

I am trying to install software with GPO at comptuer shutdown.

My first question is it is possible to do it with Software Install in Win2003 Server?

Then I tried to put a batch script to shutdown script of computer from GPO. Script is like that:

```
if exist c:\mydlp-0.7.12.txt goto end
echo %date% %time% >> c:\mydlp-0.7.12.txt
msiexec /i \\10.0.0.201\deploy\mydlp-endpoint-0.7.12.msi /qb /passive /forcerestart /l* C:\log.txt
:end
```

It does not install it on shutdown, it starts to install however it does not complete installation. However, when I run batch script normally it runs and installs software successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, why are you choosing the install software on shutdown? surely using the group policy to deploy software would be more efficant and cause less problems?

Comment: Our users are not patient enough to wait software installation on startup :)

Answer (score 3):

The specific problem you're having is that `MSIEXEC`, called in that manner, runs asynchronously. Run it with a `start /wait msiexec ...` command and you'll get what you're looking for.

Having said that, you're replicating a subset of functionality that's already built into the Group Policy client. You should research Software Installation policy to see what it can do for you. You can create a reasonably scalable, deterministic automated software installation environment without writing any scripts. It's not perfect but it does the job in a lot of cases. It'll also be much easier for The Next Guy<sup>TM</sup> to understand than a maze of batch scripts that you'll create this way.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try that.. Our users are not patient enough to wait software installation on startup :).

Comment: My users are equally as anal :) (not all of them, in case they find this post!)

Comment: Tried it. Not working :(, still same problem. Not waiting for installation and shutting down the computer.

Comment: @Burak: I'm occupied with a Customer right now. When I get some time I'll take a look at this. Shutdown scripts will be forcibly terminated after 10 minutes, by default. How long does this install take, normally?

Comment: It is not a huge file. msi size is ~10 MBs and installed size is 20 MBs. It should not take longer than 2 mins under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Use the User logoff script. Not Computer shutdown. Network service is not available at shutdown, only at logoff.

You could copy the .msi file to the local drive and change the setup path so it doesn’t point to `\\10.0.0.201\*` but to `c:\*`.